# How can I convert list into dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to use left join function for these two datasets.
Let me call the upper one as "a", and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpgBH.png)
the lower one is "b".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knfvq.png)
But it didn't work, and I found that it's because common variable(column) used to join them are incompatible types. Thus, I wanted to join these by "link_id" but that of a is integer and that of b is character.
Both are data frame as you can see in the pictures, and I thought this would be easy to solve, by running "as.integer(b)". But the error 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer' was returned despite I saw the data type is dataframe by using str function...
And I also tried "as.integer(b$link_id)", but 'warning message : NAs introduced by coersion' was returned. But there wasn't any NA value in dataframe. When I ignore this warning message and run left_join(a, b), it still returns it can't because of incompatible types of key variable...
So what should I do now? I think currently the best option is finding the way list to dataframe.

Comment: Please share minimal sample data and expected output. See [how to ask a good R question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In short: Less verbose text. More code & data. Also make sure you share what you've tried; it helps us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `b$link_id` to numeric and then use `merge` :

```
b$link_id=as.numeric(b$link_id)
merge(a,b,by="link_id")
```

Comment: Really appreciate your fast answer. I applied this, and still warning messages : In as.numeric(b$link_id) : NAs introduced by coersion was returned. But the difference was, it worked and the file was created. Would it be OK if I ignore this warning?

Comment: I don't have the overall dataset so I cannot see why there is the warning message. Probably you have non-numeric values in your link_id columns, which have been replaced by NA, you should check your link_id names. Otherwise I suggest you to convert `a$link_id` to character and keep `b$link_id` as character and do the merge again

Comment: I'll consider it. Thank you again